# How to create Log analytics workspace for NiFi flow monitoring

Tags: apache-nifi

I have created a one NiFi work flow in the apache NiFi and want to create a Log analytics workspace for NiFi flow for monitoring in Azure. Will it be possible to monitor NiFi workflows using Log Analytics workspace? How to create Log Analytics workspace for nifi workflow?
Appreciate for your help.